# How to separate menu into different view in AngularJS ui-router application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="main">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="main.tm">Task manager</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="main.settings">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron" ui-view>
        <div class="main-viewer" ></div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Here is how states conf:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'main',
    url: '/',
    template: mainTemplate
});

$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'main.tm',
    url: '/tm',
    controller: 'tm.list',
    template: view
});

$stateProvider.state({
    name: 'main.settings',
    url: '/settings',
    controller: 'settings.ctrl',
    template: view
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tm');
```

Summary:

Now I have header (menu) and content block. Dependent on what button user press in menu `settings` or `tm` module appears in content block. Both `settings` and `tm` module is in separated directories (different modules).

The problem:
`Menu` html and container for `settings` and `tm` block (`<div ui-view></div>`) are in one HTML file. I want to separate `menu` into different module (like `settings` and `tm` are in separated modules).

What I want:

main module will be like (view pseudocode):

```
<container for menu>
<container for content>
```

Menu will be in directory `menu` and there will be files `menu.html` and `menu.ctrl.js`. It will be "injected" to container "container for menu". `tm` and `settings` already in correct directories and have their own views and controllers.

Whole code is [here](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/task-manager-ng).

**PS. One of the expected results was:**

```
<menu-component></menu-component>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron" ui-view>
        <div class="main-viewer">
            Welcome page
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Now menu logic is in the separated controller and view is in the separated html.

Comment: Can you show any capture of template?

Comment: What do you mean when you say template? I attached what I have now and what I want to achieve. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: I was looking at your repository in github, and as I see the code you put in your query, and your repository, unless it's what I see, your .html files are inside a specific folder, but I do not know if that's it That I do not see the exact route in your query.

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Sounds like all you want is to create a directive or component for menu

Comment: @charlietfl Hi! I tried to explain my problem better. Is it more clear what I want now?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales I tried to explain my problem more clear. Can you understand me now?

Comment: Well, as I understand it, you have two containers, and I understand that when you press an option in the menu, what happens or should happen is that you load the template corresponding to that option in the container below. Now, do you want to create directives for each container and display only these?

Comment: True. That's the answer. I can just hide menu logic and view in the directive/component. Thank you.